# MATLAB - Partial Sums of a series using a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to write a script in MATLAB which calculates and displays the first 5 terms of the series shown in the screenshot below (I do not know how to enter equations and special characters on here sorry) using a single for loop. I am pretty new to MATLAB and the problem is throwing me off as I am also supposed to come up with a solution without using `prod` or `sum` or `factorial` commands or similar. Would really appreciate a nice detailed answer that has a model answer for the question, possibly using different values so I can solve the actual question on my own.

[Partial Sums Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le0Tk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a single `for` loop, you could display and calculate the terms individually and have an accumulator variable to get the overall sum, like so:

```
function accumulator = partial_sums(x, iters)
    accumulator = 0;  % sum of the terms
    fact_part = 1;  % factorial of the current term
    for n = 1:iters
        fact_part = fact_part * (n + 1) * (n + 2);
        term = ((-1) ^ n) * (4 * n) * (x ^ (2 * n)) / fact_part;
        fprintf('Term n = %i is %f.\n', n, term);
        accumulator = accumulator + term;
    end
end
```

This function takes in the value for the variable `x` used in the partial sums series, and the number of iterations (`iters`) to be run (aka terms to calculate).

The `fact_part` variable to store the current factorial, which I increased with every loop, since the `factorial` built-in is illegal, as is using another loop that could be used to calculate the factorial another way.

The function then calculated the current `term` for each loop, displayed it on the next line (as requested), and added it to the `accumulator` variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! It is really helpful but could you please elaborate on how the `fact_part` variable works? It is supposed to be representing (2n+1)!  right? I am a bit confused and would love some clarification!

Comment: The `fact_part` works by acting for the (2n+1)! part. Since that factorial increases by multiplying by two more numbers, I'm able to calculate every successive `fact_part` by working off of the last one: `fact_part = fact_part * (n + 1) * (n + 2)` and avoiding using another loop or the `factorial` function.
For example, the first term's denominator is `3! = 1 * 2 * 3`, and the second term's factorial is `5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5`, which is the last one but also with `* 4 * 5`.